# JSON with EDI => XML/CSV/EDI/Txt

Tags: json, edi

I'm trying to create a JSON structure for EDI. Input file will be EDI. i need to retrieve the EDI values via JSON and generate an user defined XML/EDI.

I see a json to json mapping in the link: http://www.altova.com/mapforce/json-data-mapping.html

I don't need a mapping but i need to retrieve the EDI values and have the incoming EDI structure in JSON format.

Could someone please share your thoughts on the same?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Json is a format, if you tagged the post with a programming language of your preference you could get some answers.

Comment: Every time I see this question on my feed I keep wondering what x86 registers have to do with JSON - maybe they added a special instruction set? Something like `mov json0_key, eax` `mov json0_value, dword ptr[edi]`... 

Answer (score 0):

Mapping is the way I use with Altova Mapforce.

First of all you can construct a mapping from EDI to XML and vice versa. Then let Mapforce create the code for it e.g. in C Sharp.

Unfortunately a mapping from EDI to JSON in combination with the code generator is not supported in Mapforce. So we have to do a little side step.

You can use little helper tools like Newtonsofts JSON and convert the XML to a json array. This will allow you to work with object structures in combination with EDI.

In case you use the code generator from Mapforce the working order is like:

EDI - XML - JSON to generate your json from an edi document

JSON - XML - EDI to generate your json to an edi document

Answer (score 0):

Stedi has an [EDI translator](https://www.stedi.com/products/edi-translate) which converts X12 EDI to and from JSON. There is also a [mapper](https://www.stedi.com/products/mappings) to further transform the shape of the JSON on either end. Disclosure: Stedi affiliated.

(edit: disclosure)

Comment: Do you have any affiliation with stedi?